# Create, write, and save a csv file with data from (BluetoothGattCharacteristic) characteristic.getValue()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am new to Andriod dev and I am trying to build an app that connects to a Ble device which can be used to create a CSV file and store the values of any characteristic that has a notify property. I have implemented onCharacteristicChanged(..) and am able to receive the raw bytes once I am subscribed to the characteristic.

However, I don't know how I should go about creating a CSV file and writing these raw bytes until I have unsubscribed from the characteristic or disconnected from the device. Please help.

**Edit:**
I am trying to write it with CSVWriter and I call the following method every time I get a onCharacteristicChanged callback:

```
    private void broadcastUpdate(final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, byte[] value){
       if(isCharacteristicNotifiable(characteristic)){
           String value_str =  bytesToHex(value);
           if(characteristic.getUuid().toString() == TX_CHARACTERISTIC){
              value_str =  bytestoformat(characteristic.getValue());
           }
           String[] line = value_str.split(" ");
           Log.i("broadcastUpdate",  value_str);
           try {
               CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv, true));
               writer.writeNext(line);
               writer.close();

           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
    }
```

The number of bytes I get for each characteristic change is either 2 bytes or 4 bytes. So the CSV file should be printing 4 hex values in 1 line and leave 2 values blank when there are only 2 bytes of data.

However, if the first notification gives 2 bytes of data then my entire file only shows 2 bytes of data for every change (even if 4 bytes of data are being received after the first notification). And if the first notification has 4 bytes of data then I get what I want.

Answer (score 0):

A CSV file can be created like any other file. First open a file to write to:

```
String header = "";
File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/CharNotifyData.csv");
if (!file.exists()) {
    file.createNewFile();
    header = "Characteristic;Value\n";
}
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(),true);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
bw.write(header);
```

Write your values like this:

```
bw.write(characteristicName + ";" + value + "\n");
```

Don't forget to close the file with:

```
bw.close();
```

**Edit:**
Try to differentiate between the two possible states. One way could look like this:

```
private void broadcastUpdate(final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, byte[] value){
   if(isCharacteristicNotifiable(characteristic)){
       String value_str =  bytesToHex(value);
       if(characteristic.getUuid().toString() == TX_CHARACTERISTIC){
          value_str =  bytestoformat(characteristic.getValue());
       }
       String[] line = value_str.split(" ");
       String[] fullLine = new String[4];
       for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
          if(i < line.length){
             fullLine[i] = line[i];
          }else{
             fullLine[i] = "";
          }
       }
       Log.i("broadcastUpdate",  value_str);
       try {
           CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv, true));
           writer.writeNext(line);
           writer.close();

       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: @Prasenjit see mine as well!